# A vector $\vec v = p_2 - p_1$ is pointing from $p_2$ to $p_1$ or $p_1$ to $p_2$

Tags: vectors

I have lost my intuitive feeling for vectors as defined by two points. Can someone provide me an intuitive explanation as to which way the vector should point?

Comment: Let $p_1$ be the origin. Is $v$ pointing to or from $p_2$? That's how I always remember

Comment: You can replace the vectors with real numbers (which are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^1$), and note that $3-1$ points in the direction of $3$ from $1$ (i.e. the positive direction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider points $p_1$ and $p_2$ as vectors with origin in $(0, 0)$. Then:

$$\vec p_2 = \vec p_1 + \vec v$$

Is it more intuitive?

Answer (score 2):

The vector $p_2-p_1$ is what you need to add to $p_1$ to get $p_2$, that is: $(p_2-p_1)+p_1=p_2$. Therefore, $p_2-p_1$ points from $p_1$ to $p_2$.

For example, $(2,0)-(1,0)=(1,0)$ which points from $(1,0)$ to $(2,0)$. Clearly $(2,0)=(1,0)+(1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Silly explanation: $p_2-p_1$ means that $p_2$ is losing something ($-p_1$), so $p_2$ is being hit (by an arrow). The arrow goes **from** $p_1$ **to** $p_2$.